# Which is easier? iText or Mail Merge

Tags: java, pdf, itext, doc, mailmerge

I'm working on a project for a school fundraiser and I'm supposed to be able to output results onto a PDF or Word Doc that I could easily automate to print out a sheet with the same page content but different results. I'm hoping I would be able to make the page look interesting as well, with bright colors and images.

I've been looking around and these two things caught my eye, which would you suggest I use? iText or Mail Merge with Office? (if you reccommend one over the other, can you also add resources for me to use?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Mail Merge, no question about it. Of course ultimately iText gives you the power to rewrite the whole page based on where you are sending it (like making a report), but that is not what you are looking for. If by "different results" you mean things like the donor's name and amount of donation, then go for the Mail Merge.

If you are saying you have all kinds different bar charts and content differences per person, then I might think differently, but unless you are a super-amazing high school programmer, you aren't figuring out iText in time to get that done. It is a relatively big deal, programming wise, to put together a PDF from scratch using iText, compared to putting something together in Microsoft Word.

Comment: I wouldn't say that iText is that hard to figure out - you can after all generate HTML and have iText turn that into a pdf, but the main sticking point is the restrictive Affero GPL licence - http://itextpdf.com/terms-of-use/agpl.php

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jishai about keeping it simple if time is likely to be short (as it might be with funder-raiser schedule).  Possibly the [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) or [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com/) systems might be very handy since they have command line calls you can use to have documents generated base on a mail-merge requirement.

Hope that helps.